# Elastic Search Vs Django elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, dsl

I just started learning Elastic Search and doing so I came across Django Elastic Search . SO my question is that whether they both are same or different. Also if you can give a little detail about both . Thnaku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch is an search engine buit on top of Apache Lucene, it allows you to index and search for data using REST and JSON, you can read more about it in the [official site](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch).

Django Elasticsearch is a django package to integrate with elasticsearch, it is a client built on top of the official elasticsearch python client, it allows you to integrate your application with elasticsearch, you can read more about it [here](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html).

To resume, Django Elasticsearch is a client to integrate Django applications with Elasticsearch.